# Viewing values of variables in GitLab finished jobs

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci

It is possible to parametrize GitLab jobs with variables: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/ however, the documentation doesn't say, and from the UI it is not clear whether it is possible to view the values of the variables after the job was started.  Specifically, I'm talking about the variables that show up in the

```
https://gitlab.com/<project>/pipelines/new
```

page.  Sorry, I don't understand which of the list of the variables in documentation relates to those appearing on this page.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can easily print them in your console or even better store them in a .txt file and deploy it into your pipeline's artifacts.

For example:

```
myjob:
    stage: mystage
    script:
        - echo $CI_PROJECT_DIR
        - mkdir variables
        - cd variables
        - echo $CI_PROJECT_DIR>>variables.txt
    artifacts:
        expire_in: 1 week
        when: always
        paths:
        - variables/
```